# How to assign a unique ID to an entire dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of dataframes consisting of date time and precipitation data that I would like to later merge and plot by station ID. The station ID is present in the "header" of the df but I am not able to reason out how to assign the entire df a unique ID based on it. The .csv file name that the df is constructed from also has the station ID in the name.

For clarification, I am reading in each .csv file from path using an if statement within a loop to differentiate between the different file names and adjust the column headers as needed.

Reading in each file, where 8085 is part of the filename, looks like

```
def function:
    if '8085' in file:
        df = pd.read_csv(path + file, usecols=['Variable', 'Date', 'Time', 'FPR-D Oil'], names=['Variable', 'Date', 'Time', 'FPR-D Oil'], header = None, parse_dates = [[1,2]], skiprows=[0,1])
        df_fprd_oil = df[df['Variable'].str.contains('Precip')]
```

Example of the .csv file before reading in:

```
Station ID,Sensor Serial Num,
12345678,sn123456789,
Precip,02/01/2020,09:45:00,-2.19,
Batt Voltage,02/01/2020,09:45:00,13.4,
Temp In Box,02/01/2020,09:45:00,-2.58,
Precip,02/01/2020,10:00:00,-2.19,
Batt Voltage,02/01/2020,10:00:00,13.6,
Temp In Box,02/01/2020,10:00:00,-2.17,
```

Example of the df after reading in:

```
                Date_Time  Variable  FPR-D Oil
0     2020-02-01 09:45:00   Precip      -2.19
3     2020-02-01 10:00:00   Precip      -2.19
6     2020-02-01 10:15:00   Precip      -2.19
```

What (I think) is desired

```
       Date_Time           Station ID   Variable    FPR-D Oil
0     2020-02-01 09:45:00  12345678      Precip      -2.19
3     2020-02-01 10:00:00  12345678      Precip      -2.19
6     2020-02-01 10:15:00  12345678      Precip      -2.19
```

Or maybe even

```
                Date_Time   Variable  FPR-D Oil     Unique ID
0     2020-02-01 09:45:00   Precip      -2.19            1
3     2020-02-01 10:00:00   Precip      -2.19            1
6     2020-02-01 10:15:00   Precip      -2.19            1
```

Comment: your example df after reading does not match your sample csv

Comment: @Yo_Chris this is because I am only interested in working with the rows that contain precip values. I've added context above to show this

Comment: Also, is there really a trailing comma at the end of every row in the csv indicating a blank column?

Comment: @Yo_Chris Yes in the raw file there is a trailing comma

Comment: One more question, there are two station id's in the sample csv file: `12345678,123456789,` which one corresponds to the file?

Comment: @Yo_Chris the first ```12345678``` is the station ID. I've edited it by adding sn before the second for clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming, based on your comments above, that the station id is always located at the second row of the first column in all the csv files.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# sample data
s = """Station ID,Sensor, Serial Num,
12345678,123456789,
Precip,02/01/2020,09:45:00,-2.19,
Batt Voltage,02/01/2020,09:45:00,13.4,
Temp In Box,02/01/2020,09:45:00,-2.58,
Precip,02/01/2020,10:00:00,-2.19,
Batt Voltage,02/01/2020,10:00:00,13.6,
Temp In Box,02/01/2020,10:00:00,-2.17,"""

# read your file
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), usecols=['Variable', 'Date', 'Time', 'FPR-D Oil'],
                 skiprows=[0,1], names=['Variable', 'Date', 'Time', 'FPR-D Oil'])

# read it again but only get the first value of the second row
sid = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), skiprows=1, nrows=1, header=None)[0].iloc[0]

# filter and copy so you are not assign to a slice of a frame
new_df = df[df['Variable'] == 'Precip'].copy()

# assign sid to a new column
new_df.loc[:, 'id'] = sid

print(new_df)

  Variable        Date      Time  FPR-D Oil        id
0   Precip  02/01/2020  09:45:00      -2.19  12345678
3   Precip  02/01/2020  10:00:00      -2.19  12345678
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I knew there had to be a way to utilize the site ID that's already in the .csv. The other suggestions also work due to the way I have my functions set up but I like that this is more automated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add `UniqueID` to your Dataframe and want it to be constant for one dataframe then you can simply do this.

`df["UniqueID"] = 1`

It will add a column named `UniqueID` in your existing `df` with the assigned value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was trying to keep it as simple as possible and I think I should have been more clear in my question. I think? I updated it to better reflect my issue. I am reading in each file from path using a loop and if-else statement to differentiate between the different .csv formats and station ID's to change the column headers as needed. So I would like it to automatically assign a unique ID to each file as it executes the function each time..   EDIT: my logic was flawed and I think this actually will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Station ID'] = 12345678
```

Where df is your dataframe